# What will happen to the foreground service if the notification was blocked?

Tags: android, android-service

We know can't start foreground service without notification but if the user blocked the notification before launch the foreground service what will happen?

Comment: Notification does not blocked during foreground service

Comment: if it happens then system will show notification or alarm to the user that this application is running in background

Comment: @YaqoobBhatti There is no any alert, When I block notification the foreground service still running, Is it legal?

Comment: it consuming battery in some other devices system will alert

Comment: when the user see this alert he will uninstall the app or stop app